# Small suitcase with top-loading? Does it exist?

Tags: luggage

I usually just use carry-ons because I can take out and put stuff in without having to lay it down horizontally but due a recent physical issue I need a suitcase that can be loaded and unloaded from the top...are there any companies that make such a thing?  I'm absolutely not looking for backpack/trekking type bags but more wheeled luggage or not...

Edit:Yes, like a pilot style bag that's carry on size or larger is fine.  So, are there suitcases that can be fully functional standing upright with no need lay it horizontal or must I buy bags catered to pilots?  Cause the pilot ones are so low profile you REALLY have to bend though it is top loading...

Edit 2.0: I'm looking for suitcase/bags (even with no wheels) such as the Briggs U116... it opens up top but a bit too tiny for a week of travel stuff, yes?  :-) Those cases made for computer storage are too tiny as well...so it doesn't exist?  A bag with structure would be awesome.

Comment: Don't all suitcases load from the top? ([Example](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-n5z5MdFZztM/Tc1yHAyCt0I/AAAAAAAABQw/RwYM1YxXZqU/s1600/open+suitcase.gif)) Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a suitcase can be loaded while standing upright, and not flat.

Comment: Are you looking for a carry on sized bag, or a large sized suitcase? the first thing that came to my mind was [this tote from waterfield](http://www.sfbags.com/collections/totes/products/outback-canvas-travel-tote) but its for carry on.

Comment: A "pilots' bag" may meet your need. I have occasionally seen much larger ones that those that you typically see eg pilots carrying.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a large enough briefcase.

Comment: Yes, like a pilot bag style or any suitcase that can be loaded and unloaded upright.

Comment: @Burhan That is wide open with no wheels.

Comment: Have you tried [Jetsettr website](http://www.jetsettr.com.au/)? I believe they have the particular type of luggage that you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: Samsonite rolling backpack works great. Even better with packing cubes.

Answer (score 8):

I did some sleuthing for you - as I was also looking for an upgrade to my normal travel bag.

Searches for [sample case](http://www.thefind.com/office/info-wheeled-sample-case), [catalog case](http://www.irvsluggage.com/p/71313?source=pjn&subid=3578) and pilot case led to some promising finds.

However all of these are designed to hold documents, so don't expect a lot of utility out of them. They do fit your requirements - they open from the top, are wheeled.

The largest I could find was [this item](http://www.amazon.co.uk/vojagor%C2%AE-PLKO01-Wheeled-Executive-Business/dp/B008QWJXO8) over at Amazon UK:

[image]

Which is 46x23x35 centimeters.

I think if you need something bigger, you'll have to search for specialized equipment cases.

[Tenba](http://www.tenba.com/) is a good company to ask, as they make custom cases for transporting equipment. For example:

[image]

Another option would be to buy a large backpack, and then attach a roller caddy to it. I did this once when I got tired of lugging around my camera bag.

Comment: (It would be quite funny to see their transport case for the new "nuclear cooling tower" powermac :) )

Answer (score 1):

A wheeled duffel bag may suit your purpose to a degree.  Most are designed to be laid down and opened, but because of their soft sides and wrap around zipper, they can be opened part way while sitting upright and items retrieved or put in.

But like most top loading bags, the stuff at the top is easily accessible, the stuff further down requires grasping around without seeing what you are grabbing or unpacking everything on top first.

Answer (score 1):

I have one of [these](http://www.menswearhouse.com/mens-clothes/luggage/garment-bags/skyroll-all-in-one-carry-on-suitcase-garment-bag-891100) (or see [here](http://www.skyroll.com/skyroll-spinner/) also) , seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

[image]

[image]

Its main selling point is the garment bag that you can wrap around it. But whether you choose to use that or not, the top unzips completely and you can use it for access inside. Actually, if you have wrapped up the garment bag around it, the top is the only way to get inside. 
Alternatively, when you're packing, you would be able to open up the larger zipper on its side.

And you can take it up as carry-on.

Comment: I can't find pics of it with an open lid...does it open at the top even when being carried/wheeled?

Comment: Yes, in the pic above it's on its side, so the top lid is the one on the left. That opens at all times. The one facing us in the picture is the one I refer to as the side one which you can use for packing but not so much when its standing.

Comment: Who is the maker?  Is that the wheel sticking out on top...what is the purpose of that?

Comment: As I said above, this is sitting on its side in the picture, it is not in its upright position. The top is to the left of this picture, the bottom (with 2 wheels) is to the right.

Comment: Here's a better link with pictures: http://www.skyroll.com/skyroll-spinner/

Comment: Yes...the right is the bottom...:-) was wondering why the maker decided to have the housing of the wheels extend beyond the width of the suitcase?

Comment: I can only guess :) But I think it's for stability, with the suitcase being rather tall and narrow.

Comment: Sweet, this is carry-on size?  That's nice.  :-) Small company?  Is the quality good? Rugged?

Answer (score 0):

OP, just to be clear are you aware that while some "briefcases" load like this:

[image]

in fact many (most?) load like this:

[image]

That's just what you want right?

You could say, all **"soft briefcases**" load exactly as you describe!

In English, arguably the upper type (what you DON'T want) is more called an "attaché case", whereas the bottom one that you do want is perhaps called a "legal" briefcase, or indeed just a briefcase.

You also get [this sort of thing](http://www.originalblackfriday.com/img/alpine-swiss-rolling-briefcase-on-wheels-good-for-sample-catalog-pilot-attache-case-lawyers-briefcase-legal-size-laptop-case-sleeve-overnight-bag-carry-on-luggage-w-1-year-mfgs-warranty_853911_500.jpg) if you really have to pack stuff in. Bon voyage!

Comment: Yes, these lawyer type cases do exist. Duh. ;-) I meant an actual clothes suitcase the unzips completely upright...like you can reach in and grab everything in the same position it would be rolling or carrying around. Ceiling facing top open.

Comment: OK.  Sorry your question wasn't very clear. Burhan seems to have given some excellent suggestions!