# Hard-case suitcase, that doesn't open at the side

Tags: luggage

I am looking for a hard-case, light-weight bag like the one pictured, however with a zipper on top (the yellow line) rather than at the side. This would allow to open the bag without using a lot of space as in the original layout.

Has anybody of you seen a bag like this or does somebody know where to buy something like this?

[image]

Comment: IMHO Shopping recommendations are off topic, and specifically in your case, with enough financial motivation someone may custom create it for you and where I live (India) http://www.snapdeal.com/product/novex-hard-luggage-bags-maroon/966756086 is an option that I could find first in google

Comment: The bag in the link you posted does have the zipper at the side. This is NOT what I want.

Comment: can you post a link to an image that makes you believe it does, because I checked them and I could not make out one

Comment: http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/p/j/Novex-Hard-Luggage-Bags-Maroon-SDL669270090-4-d70c5.jpg  When you open this bag, it uses double the space compared to the closed bag (lying).

Comment: There are nylon backpack type roller bags that do what you want.  But ultimately if the suitcase is hard sided, the panel (being zipped open) will be hard sided and will take up nearly the same space as the original suitcase when opened.

Comment: @skv This doesn't sound like a shopping recommendation to me ("what's the best bag?"), he's asking whether a very specific and unusual product exists.

Comment: @jpatokal I agree, the line is generally very thin and hence my opinion, but at the time of making that comment I had assumed he wanted a rather normal product (which I found was wrong after the comment clarification)

Comment: @Tom The trick is to open the panel only 90° and leaning it against a wall. In hotels there's very often a place where you can put your bag (http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/06/c8/5b/28/comfort-hotel-lichtenberg.jpg ) but it is usually to small for an open large bag like the one pictured. If the bag opened as I wished, it would work perfectly though.

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37249/small-suitcase-with-top-loading-does-it-exist

Comment: Delsey. Top lid zipper into main area. Also middle zipper. I was googling it and seen this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, I am not the only one who is interested in such a suitcase: Samsonite released a new series last year, called "Spin Trunk". It "translates to a 20% light lid compartment and an 80% maximised base compartment for easy packing."

[image: Ad showing the suitcase]

Not exactly what I want, but one step towards the ultimate suitcase.

Answer (score 5):

I think your main question is, how to access the contents of the bag, without having to split it open, thus minimizing the space required to access internal contents.

The design of these bags is for maximizing the interior space, which is why almost all open in the same clamshell fashion. They are primarily designed to safely carry the contents inside and quick access is not a top usability priority.

A bag like the one you describe could only come with an accordian-type opening on the top  so that you can perhaps access the contents of a smaller compartment. Having the entire bag accessible while upright is not possible as the contents would tumble out due to the orientation.

There are some "hybrid" cases, but I question the practicality of these.

Here are some examples:

[image: The Floati Suitcase (Kickstarter)]

(From the [floatti kickstarter campaign](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1491048568/floatti-the-worlds-first-super-suitcase))

[image]
[image]

([Enkloze X1 Carbon](https://www.enkloze.com/shop/enkloze-x1-carbon-black-carry-on-spinner))

[image]

([Sienna 21" Hybrid Garment Bag](https://www.luggagepros.com/traveler-s-choice-tc-luggage-sienna-21-hybrid-expandable-carry-on-wheeled-upright-garment-bag.shtml))

Samsonite has an excellent case (in their Lite-Box series) that offers the same space in both the lid and the base:

[image]

To lie it flat on on side, to simply open the top (like a can) takes the same amount of space as splitting the bag open, since you can open it 90 degrees. Having a specific case like that would eat into its practicality - of course there are specialized cases that are designed to be loaded and used upright. My favorite of these is the [1440 by Pelican](https://www.pelican.com/us/en/product/cases/top-loader-case/protector/1440), which looks rather rugged but it is extremely reliable:

[image]

(The [Pelican 1440](https://www.pelican.com/us/en/product/cases/top-loader-case/protector/1440) (with [optional internal organizer](https://www.pelican.com/us/en/accessory/cases/office-divider-set--amp--lid-organizer/1446)))

Comment: Thanks, very interesting thoughts. My main question is actually slightly different: Why do "soft" trolley open like this: https://www.samsonite.lu/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-samsonite-product-catalog/default/dwc6692009/images/gene/prod/zoom/92615-1041_02.jpg while "hard" trolleys don't?

Answer (score 3):

Victorinox Spectra answers the question exactly:

[image]

[image]

The middle zipper is for expansion.

Comment: Can you please expand this answer to include (a link to) a picture?

Comment: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5117/4188

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been looking for the same sort of luggage myself, and I’ve found one I like. Checkout the Delsey Shadow luggage.

[https://www.amazon.com/25-Inch-Expandable-Spinner-Trolley-Platinum/dp/B00VISP3F0/ref=mp_s_a_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1547535767&sr=8-6&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_QL65&keywords=delsey%2Bshadow%2Bluggage&dpPl=1&dpID=41gk4Sm1pUL&ref=plSrch&th=1&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VISP3F0)

Answer (score 1):

In Spain, I purchased a hard-sided **soft-top** bag with the zipper where your yellow line suggests.  But I bought it at a *chino*—a store that has all kinds of things low cost, and mostly low quality.  (Spanish call them *chino* because they are always run by people who look Chinese, but at least one I went to was Vietnamese.)

Cost €30 for the largest size (bigger than most airlines’ check-in limit), and after one cruise and a plane flight, the plastic that made it hard-sided is in at least a dozen pieces, and part of the roller frame has come apart.  I only needed it for one trip, and expected it to be worth three trips, but obviously I overestimated.  If it were made of slightly better materials, it would actually have been a very good bag.

Unfortunately, all branding information was a single logo stuck on the front/top which fell off on the way out of the store.  But they had four or more sizes, from this giant down to under-seat size.